# Create a custom history entity for multiple entities

Tags: java, javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I am wanting to create a custom history entity that will hold inactive records from another entity but am wanting to achieve this on 3 different entities.

Is it possible to create an entity that say may have a iFrame which will show the entity and just display the view of only inactive records?

Or do you know a better way to achieve this?

all help is appricated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do the directly in he product. However, You could create a custom entity to hold the data you are interested in, then create a workflow to create new record based on this entity when you primary entity is deactivated.

You can find examples of each of these steps in the SDK.